# Three.js click point on sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make an object with points that are created when the mouse clicks on a sphere. the camera is inside the sphere and I want to make clickable areas mapped onto the sphere.

Something like https://threejs.org/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html

```
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;
    mouse.z = 0.5;


    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    var objects = [];
    objects.push(panoVideoMesh);
    panoVideoMesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true  );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ){

        var point = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({  color: 0x00ff00 }));
        point.position.copy(intersects[0].point);
        point.lookAt(camera);
        panoVideoMesh.add(point);
    }
```

This kind of works but the meshes being added are not in the same place as the mouse click, and when you rotate the camera by clicking and dragging the scene (it's a VR scene) the points are all on the same plane.

Any help/clues!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`intersects[0].point` is in world coordinates, but you add `point` as a descendant of `panoVideoMesh`. The transforms of both objects get mixed together. You must either add `point` directly to the scene, or first convert the intersection point to be in `panoVideoMesh`'s local space.